# Spring initialize Errors interface in controller class

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I'm having an issue with some validations I'm running in my project. I'm trying to validate some arguments inside an object I created in my controller, recieving an String in the first place.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/publicar", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST }, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ApiPubPortalPublicarOut publicar(@RequestParam(value = PARAM_XML) String xml, Locale locale) {
            //This object is my return, it creates an XML with the validation.
            ApiPubPortalPublicarOut xmlTaxOut = new ApiPubPortalPublicarOut();
            Errors result = null; //Here is the problem

            //validate incoming xml is empty
            if ((xml == null) || (xml.length() == 0)) {
                xmlTaxOut.setDescription("xml is Empty!");
                return xmlTaxOut;
            }else{
                try{
                    //I transform the xml into an object
                    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(ApiPubPortalPublicarPortal.class);
                    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
                    StreamSource streamSource = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xmlEntrada));
                    JAXBElement<ApiPubPortalPublicarPortal> je = unmarshaller.unmarshal(streamSource, ApiPubPortalPublicarPortal.class);

                    //Here is the validation method.
                     parsingPublicacion(je.getValue(), result, locale);
                     if(result.hasErrors()){
                        xmlTaxOut.setDescription(result.getAllErrors().toString());
                        return xmlTaxOut;
                     }
                }catch(Exception){
                    xmlTaxOut.setDescription("Error parsing!");
                    return xmlTaxOut;
                }
            }
        }
```

This is my controller, as you can see I try to transform my string into an object, then I call the Method `parsingPublicacion` in order to do my validations.

The main problem is I can't initialize my `Errors` parameter because its an interface, anyone knows how I can manage this validation?

This is mi validator method.

```
private void parsingPublicacion(ApiPubPortalPublicarPortal portalPublicado,  Errors e, Locale locale) {
    ApiPubPortalPublicarPortal pubPortal = portalPublicado;

    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(e, "name", "name.empty"));
    if (pubPortal.getNombre().length() > 50){
        e.rejectValue("name", "name.oversize");
    }

    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(e, "idLanguage.empty");
    if ((pubPortal.getIdPortal() == 0)){
        e.rejectValue("idLanguage", "idLanguage.zero"));
    }

}
```

I can't call Errors from the method because I only allowed to call specific paremeters in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Edit 2 Since you don't have a model attribute you need to use a concrete class that implements Errors. [BeanPropertyBindingResult](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/BeanPropertyBindingResult.html) is such one.

You can use the **BeanPropertyBindingResult** as follows

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/publicar", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST }, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ApiPubPortalPublicarOut publicar(@RequestParam(value = PARAM_XML) String xml, Locale locale) {
    //This object is my return, it creates an XML with the validation.
    ApiPubPortalPublicarOut xmlTaxOut = new ApiPubPortalPublicarOut();


    //validate incoming xml is empty
    if ((xml == null) || (xml.length() == 0)) {
        xmlTaxOut.setDescription("xml is Empty!");
        return xmlTaxOut;
    }else{
        try{
            //I transform the xml into an object
            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(ApiPubPortalPublicarPortal.class);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
            StreamSource streamSource = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xmlEntrada));
            JAXBElement<ApiPubPortalPublicarPortal> je = unmarshaller.unmarshal(streamSource, ApiPubPortalPublicarPortal.class);

            // Using concrete implementation of error interface
            BeanPropertyBindingResult result = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(je.getValue(), "apiPubPortal");


            //Here is the validation method.
            parsingPublicacion(je.getValue(), result, locale);
            if(result.hasErrors()){
                xmlTaxOut.setDescription(result.getAllErrors().toString());
                return xmlTaxOut;
            }
        }catch(Exception){
            xmlTaxOut.setDescription("Error parsing!");
            return xmlTaxOut;
        }
    }
}
```

> Edit 1
>   You can use Error interface as method parameter too. And Spring will still populate an implementation.

Use [BindigResults](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/BindingResult.html) as **method argument** and use it in places of **Error**. Spring will automatically populate an implementation for you.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/publicar", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST }, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ApiPubPortalPublicarOut publicar(@RequestParam(value = PARAM_XML) String xml,
                                        BindingResult result, Locale locale) {
            //This object is my return, it creates an XML with the validation.
            ApiPubPortalPublicarOut xmlTaxOut = new ApiPubPortalPublicarOut();
            // Use BindingResult in places of erros


        }
```

***BindingResult*** extends Errors, so you will have the functionalities of error in it.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-arguments

Comment: I tried that and it throws: `java.lang.IllegalStateException An Errors/BindingResult argument is expected to be declared immediately after the model attribute, the @RequestBody or the @RequestPart arguments to which they apply: public`

Comment: Oh, I see! You should have a ModelAttribute for this to work. If you don't have one You can use BeanPropertyBindingResult it's a concrete class and you can use it directly.

Comment: I see, now... I need to add some arguments to initalize it and that confuses me a bit. What arguments I need?

Comment: @AngelJaramillo update 2 should work fine. Let me know.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! Update 2 is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can Binding Result & FieldErrors instead of Errors. Please find the below code.

private void parsingPublicacion(ApiPubPortalPublicarPortal portalPublicado,  BindingResult bindingResult, Locale locale) {
    ApiPubPortalPublicarPortal pubPortal = portalPublicado;
    String[] codes = {"errorCode"};
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(e, "name", "name.empty"));
    if (pubPortal.getNombre().length() > 50){
        e.rejectValue("name", "name.oversize");
        bindingResult.addError(new FieldError(Yourclass.getSimpleName(),"Name", pubPortal.getNombre(), false , codes , null , "name.oversize"));
    }

    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(e, "idLanguage.empty");
    if ((pubPortal.getIdPortal() == 0)){
        e.rejectValue("idLanguage", "idLanguage.zero"));
        bindingResult.addError(new `enter code here`FieldError(Yourclass.getSimpleName(),"idLanguage", pubPortal.getIdPortal(), false , codes , null , "idLanguage.zero"));
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, the main problem is how I initialize the Binding Result, because my controller I can't use it as a method argument because it needs a model attribute.